# 80's or 90's teen horror book

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm looking for an old 80's or 90's horror teen book.

The story is about a girl who's on a bus and meets another girl; one of the girls is good and the other bad. The bad girl kills the good girl and gets rid of her. She then takes over her identity and lives the previous girl's life.

On the cover of the book I believe there was a locket or something and the picture of the girl has her eyes scratched out and only the color red shows where her eyes should be and people can't understand how the eyes are scratched out without damaging the red backing paper.

I can't remember the title or author.

Answer (score 4):

I think it was the Horror High book - *[New Kid on The Block](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26093825-new-kid-on-the-block)* by Nicholas Adams.

[image: Cover with a compact] [image: Another cover]

**[Synopsis](http://www.gusworld.com.au/books/horror/4.htm):**

> Elizabeth Henley can't wait to meet Amanda Mackenzie. They've been pen pals for a year, and now Amanda is coming to Cresswell as an exchange student. But when Amanda shows up, there's something very weird about her. Then a boy is found dead in the woods. Amanda's increasingly strange behaviour causes Elizabeth to be suspicious. After a second body is found, Elizabeth realizes that the girl who is staying with her is not her pen pal. Will Elizabeth's discovery make her "Amanda"'s next victim?